# How to take a CSV field and write to columns in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv

I have the following code which takes a CSV and writes to a console:

```
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(
           new StreamReader("data.csv"), true))
    {
        // missing fields will not throw an exception,
        // but will instead be treated as if there was a null value
        csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ReplaceByNull;
        // to replace by "" instead, then use the following action:
        //csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ReplaceByEmpty;
        int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
        string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
        while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0} = {1};",
                              headers[i],
                              csv[i] == null ? "MISSING" : csv[i]));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

The CSV file has 7 headers for which I have 7 columns in my SQL table.

What is the best way to take each `csv[i]` and write to a row for each column and then move to the next row?

I tried to add the `ccsv[i]` to a string array but that didn't work.

I also tried the following:

```
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 [" + csv[i] + "]", mysqlconnectionstring);
sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My table (`table1`) is like this:

`name     address     city     zipcode     phone     fax     device`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is simple but I will take it one step further and let you know a better way to approach the issue.

when you have a problem to sold, always break it down into parts and apply each part in each own method. For example, in your case:

- 1 - read from the file
- 2 - create a sql query
- 3 - run the query

and you can even **add validation** to the file (imagine your file does not even have 7 fields in one or more lines...) and the example below it to be taken, only if your file never passes around 500 lines, as if it does normally you should consider to use a SQL statement that takes your file directly in to the database, it's called [bulk insert](https://www.google.dk/search?q=bulk%20insert%20csv%20sql&oq=bulk%20insert)

1 - read from file:

I would use a `List<string>` to hold the line entries and I always use `StreamReader` to read from text files.

```
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(this.CsvPath))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    splittedLine = line.Split(new string[] { this.Separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    if (iLine == 0 && this.HasHeader)
                        // header line
                        this.Header = splittedLine;
                    else
                        this.Lines.Add(splittedLine);

                    iLine++;
                }
            }
```

2 - generate the sql

```
        foreach (var line in this.Lines)
        {
            string entries = string.Concat("'", string.Join("','", line))
                                   .TrimEnd('\'').TrimEnd(','); // remove last ",'" 

            this.Query.Add(string.Format(this.LineTemplate, entries));
        }
```

3 - run the query

```
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(string.Join("", query), mysqlconnectionstring);
sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

having some fun I end up doing the solution and you can download it here, the output is:

[image]

**[The code can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2eb2qc66p1v3mfv/ExtractCsvIntoSql.zip)**. It needs more tweaks but I will left that for others. Solution written in C#, VS 2013.

The `ExtractCsvIntoSql` class is as follows:

```
public class ExtractCsvIntoSql
{
    private string CsvPath, Separator;
    private bool HasHeader;
    private List<string[]> Lines;
    private List<string> Query;

    /// <summary>
    /// Header content of the CSV File
    /// </summary>
    public string[] Header { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Template to be used in each INSERT Query statement
    /// </summary>
    public string LineTemplate { get; set; }

    public ExtractCsvIntoSql(string csvPath, string separator, bool hasHeader = false)
    {
        this.CsvPath = csvPath;
        this.Separator = separator;
        this.HasHeader = hasHeader;
        this.Lines = new List<string[]>();

        // you can also set this
        this.LineTemplate = "INSERT INTO [table1] SELECT ({0});";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the SQL Query
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<string> Generate()
    {
        if(this.CsvPath == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("CSV Path can't be empty");

        // extract csv into object
        Extract();
        // generate sql query 
        GenerateQuery();

        return this.Query;
    }

    private void Extract()
    {
        string line;
        string[] splittedLine;
        int iLine = 0;

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(this.CsvPath))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    splittedLine = line.Split(new string[] { this.Separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    if (iLine == 0 && this.HasHeader)
                        // header line
                        this.Header = splittedLine;
                    else
                        this.Lines.Add(splittedLine);

                    iLine++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if(ex.InnerException != null)
                while (ex.InnerException != null)
                    ex = ex.InnerException;

            throw ex;
        }

        // Lines will have all rows and each row, the column entry
    }

    private void GenerateQuery()
    {
        foreach (var line in this.Lines)
        {
            string entries = string.Concat("'", string.Join("','", line))
                                   .TrimEnd('\'').TrimEnd(','); // remove last ",'" 

            this.Query.Add(string.Format(this.LineTemplate, entries));
        }
    }
}
```

and you can run it as:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file = Ask("What is the CSV file path? (full path)");
        string separator = Ask("What is the current separator? (; or ,)");

        var extract = new ExtractCsvIntoSql(file, separator);
        var sql = extract.Generate();

        Output(sql);
    }

    private static void Output(IEnumerable<string> sql)
    {
        foreach(var query in sql)
            Console.WriteLine(query);

        Console.WriteLine("*******************************************");
        Console.Write("END ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string Ask(string question)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*******************************************");
        Console.WriteLine(question);
        Console.Write("= ");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Man!! Such a big answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will definitely test it out. The issue I was having was some of the fields had comma in them hence it was messing up my entire csv reading.

Comment: hence the validation I mentioned... it's easy to get that error if you test `splittedLine.Length` that must be the one you want. Inside the `Extract()` method.

Comment: I get an error in this line: `this.Query.Add(string.Format(this.LineTemplate, entries));` error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. I am thinking somewhere along that line I have to add the connection string, but not sure where...

Comment: If you debug, you can see that before you add the object, the `Query` property was not yet initialized, and that's why it's still `null`. You do need to learn how to debug code as well! I forgot that on propose. Just add `this.Query = new List<string>();` in the constructor, after `this.Lines = new List<string[]>();` ...

Comment: Thank you for the exact answer. The issue I am having is some fields have `""` while some have `''` while some have nothing while some fields had `'` and also while some fields are missing completely which is why everything is failing at some point. I decided to go with a SSIS package which i can schedule and it worked perfectly fine. I accepted your answer as this was the best possible solution provided.

Comment: you can always trim your entries using `.Trim('"').Trim('\'')` this way you are sure that no entries will have `"` or `'`

Answer (score 1):

Usually i like to be a bit more generic so i'll try to explain a very basic flow i use from time to time:

I don't like the hard coded attitude so even if your code will work it will be dedicated specifically to one type. I prefer i simple reflection, first to understand what DTO is it and then to understand what repository should i use to manipulate it:

For example:

```
public class ImportProvider
{
    private readonly string _path;
    private readonly ObjectResolver _objectResolver;

    public ImportProvider(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
        _objectResolver = new ObjectResolver();
    }

    public void Import()
    {
        var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(_path, "*.csv");
        foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            var className = fileName.Remove(fileName.Length-4);
            using (var reader = new CsvFileReader(filePath))
            {
                var row = new CsvRow();
                var repository = (DaoBase)_objectResolver.Resolve("DAL.Repository", className + "Dao");
                while (reader.ReadRow(row))
                {
                    var dtoInstance = (DtoBase)_objectResolver.Resolve("DAL.DTO", className + "Dto");
                    dtoInstance.FillInstance(row.ToArray());
                    repository.Save(dtoInstance);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above is a very basic class responsible importing the data. Nevertheless of how this piece of code parsing CSV files (CsvFileReader), the important part is thata "CsvRow" is a simple List.

Below is the implementation of the ObjectResolver:

```
public class ObjectResolver
{
    private readonly Assembly _myDal;
    public ObjectResolver()
    {
       _myDal = Assembly.Load("DAL");

    }
    public object Resolve(string nameSpace,  string name)
    {
        var myLoadClass = _myDal.GetType(nameSpace + "." + name); 
        return Activator.CreateInstance(myLoadClass);
    }

}
```

The idea is to simple follow a naming convetion, in my case is using a "Dto" suffix for reflecting the instances, and "Dao" suffix for reflecting the responsible dao. The full name of the Dto or the Dao can be taken from the csv name or from the header (as you wish)

Next step is filling the Dto, each dto or implements the following simple abstract:

```
public abstract class DtoBase
{
    public abstract void FillInstance(params string[] parameters);
}
```

Since each Dto "knows" his structure (just like you knew to create an appropriate table in the database), it can easily implement the FillInstanceMethod, here is a simple Dto example:

```
public class ProductDto : DtoBase
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public int FamilyId { get; set; }

    public override void FillInstance(params string[] parameters)
    {
        ProductId = int.Parse(parameters[0]);
        Weight = double.Parse(parameters[1]);
        FamilyId = int.Parse(parameters[2]);
    }
}
```

After you have your Dto filled with data you should find the appropriate Dao to handle it
which is basically happens in reflection in this line of the Import() method:

```
var repository = (DaoBase)_objectResolver.Resolve("DAL.Repository", className + "Dao");
```

In my case the Dao implements an abstract base class - but it's not that relevant to your problem, your DaoBase can be a simple abstract with a single Save() method.
This way you have a dedicated Dao to CRUD your Dto's - each Dao simply knows how to save for its relevant Dto. Below is the corresponding ProductDao to the ProductDto:

```
public class ProductDao : DaoBase
{
    private const string InsertProductQuery = @"SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
                                                Insert into product (productID, weight, familyID)
                                                VALUES (@productId, @weight, @familyId);
                                                SET foreign_key_checks = 1;";


    public override void Save(DtoBase dto)
    {
        var productToSave = dto as ProductDto;
        var saveproductCommand = GetDbCommand(InsertProductQuery);
        if (productToSave != null)
        {
            saveproductCommand.Parameters.Add(CreateParameter("@productId", productToSave.ProductId));
            saveproductCommand.Parameters.Add(CreateParameter("@weight", productToSave.Weight));
            saveproductCommand.Parameters.Add(CreateParameter("@familyId", productToSave.FamilyId));
            ExecuteNonQuery(ref saveproductCommand);
        }

    }
}
```

Please ignore the CreateParameter() method, since it's an abstraction from the base classs. you can just use a CreateSqlParameter or CreateDataParameter etc.

Just notice, it's a real naive implementation - you can easily remodel it better, depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

From the first impression of your questionc I guess you would be having hugely number of records (more than lacs). If yes I would consider the SQL bulk copies an option. If the record would be less go ahead single record. Insert. The reason for you insert not working is u not providing all the columns of the  table and also there's some syntax error.

Comment: please provide a proper answer, don't say "there's some syntax error" point out where and what to do to fix the issue... That's an answer. What you wrote should be a simple comment.