# vb.NET Arrays - Turning a String into a Table

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I am working on a windows form application, and I have it reading a text file that has information stored in the form of a table. It looks somewhat like this:

```
ID     Name      URL
1      client1   client1.com
2      client2   client2.com
3      client3   client3.com
```

And so on...
What I need to do is get this data to be read from a stream reader, that throws it into a string, including vbtabs and newlines, and then create an array out of that information, so that it acts as a table that I can then later pull information from based on the column names (i.e. ID, Name, URL) and the ID number. I do not have a lot of experience with arrays, so I was hoping to get some help here as how to do this.

The code I have so far for this functionality is:

```
Dim readCLientTxtListReader As New StreamReader(strReplicationDataClientAccessListPath)
Dim strClientAccessList As String = readCLientTxtListReader.ReadToEnd

Console.Write(strClientAccessList)
readCLientTxtListReader.Close()

Dim i As Integer
Dim aryClientAccessList() As String

aryClientAccessList = strClientAccessList.Split(vbTab)
For i = 0 To UBound(aryClientAccessList)
    Console.WriteLine(aryClientAccessList)
Next i
```

The problem about this is that it just creates a new instance of the array as each individual string of characters between each vbtab. which means, the arrays look like:

```
ID
Name
URL
1
client1
client1.com
2
client2
client2.com
3
client3
client3.com
```

Which is not really what I need.

Any ideas?

If you need more info, let me know.

Edit: As an added side-note, I believe multidimensional arrays are what I am looking for, and am currently looking them up now, but if you have any more information on these, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like a regular CSV, where delimiter is `vbTab`. Hence, I suggest you (don't reinvent the wheel and) start off reading and writing a CSV file. For example, [KBCSV](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Well, I am writing to and reading from a plain txt file.. Unless you were meaning something else?

Comment: If the delimiter is tab use the textfieldparser class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

Comment: @BobbyNicholls: CSV is also plain text, with certain formatting rules. There are standard ways of handling new lines, quotes, and escaping those if present inside values. In many open source solutions available out there it would typically be handled for you. For example, what would you do if any of the `Name` values contained a tab in it?

Comment: I am not worried about the tabs within the values, as the string is coming from a webresponse which bounces off an sql db that has very strict rules on the naming conventions. I need to be able to do this without any other solutions, all code. This is likely to be widely distributed, and our clients have requested it to be done in a certain way. 

That being said, I appreciate your help, I am starting to figure out the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The way I am reading your end goal is that you want to have an array that that contains each row of the file and that each row should be an array with the tokens for that row in it. If that is correct, then you could do something like this:

```
var lines = new List<string[]>();
using (var strReplicationDataClientAccessListPath = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(strReplicationDataClientAccessListPath))
{
    while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            lines.Add(line.Split('\t'));
    }
}
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    foreach (var token in line)
        Console.Write(token);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I have not done VB in a long time but here is the C# which can be run through a converter to get VB.NET. Also I did it using a List, if you need an array at the end you can do:

```
lines.ToArray();
```

Comment: I think that is sort of what I am going for, but not sure just yet. let's see if the converted code works.

Answer (score 0):

This is rclements code
converted to VB

```
Dim lines = New List(Of String())()
Using strReplicationDataClientAccessListPath = New FileStream("path", FileMode.Open)
  Using streamReader = New StreamReader(strReplicationDataClientAccessListPath)
    While streamReader.Peek() >= 0
      Dim line = streamReader.ReadLine()
      If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then
        lines.Add(line.Split(ControlChars.Tab))
      End If
    End While
  End Using
End Using
For Each line As var In lines
  For Each token As var In line
    Console.Write(token)
  Next
  Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Comment: thank you for translating, but I am still not convinced that this is what I need. Let me give it a try.

Comment: did you use Telerk to convert? there is a syntax error in the code! please check before you post, there is no type of "var" in VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to simulate `CSV -> DataTable` workflow, where `vbTab` is your CSV delimiter, and `DataTable` is your storage structure (you can query by field name, and by row index). There are numerous solutions on the internet, just google for `CSV to DataTable`.

Here is [one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F), linked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1050149/897326) (SO answer).

If you still want multi-dimensional arrays, I recommended a `List(Of String())` instead of `String(,)`, because you would then *not* need to manage memory allocation. Each line of data would be an element of `List`, and a single dimension array, where column values are array elements `0-N`.

To read from file, you can use [IO.File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you need?

```
    'Read Values from the text file and store in a DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using TextReader As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Data.txt")
        Dim Line As String = TextReader.ReadLine

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Line) Then
            MsgBox("No Data")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        With Line.Split(vbTab)
            dt.Columns.Add(.GetValue(0))
            dt.Columns.Add(.GetValue(1))
            dt.Columns.Add(.GetValue(2))
        End With

        Do
            Line = TextReader.ReadLine
            If Line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            dt.Rows.Add(Line.Split(vbTab))
        Loop
    End Using

    'Print the DataTable header
    For Each Column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        Console.Write(Column.ColumnName & vbTab)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & New String("-", 24))

    'Print the DataTable contents
    For Each Row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Console.WriteLine(Row("ID") & vbTab & Row("Name") & vbTab & Row("URL"))
    Next
```

I have added another solution using `List` in case you prefer it more than the `DataTable`:

```
    'Read Values from the text file and store in a List of type Tuples
    Dim Values As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String, String))

    Using TextReader As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Data.txt")
        Dim Line As String = TextReader.ReadLine

        Do Until Line Is Nothing
            With Line.Split(vbTab)
                Values.Add(Tuple.Create(.GetValue(0).ToString, .GetValue(1).ToString, .GetValue(2).ToString))
            End With
            Line = TextReader.ReadLine
        Loop
    End Using

    'Print the List contents
    For Each T As Tuple(Of String, String, String) In Values
        Console.WriteLine(T.Item1 & vbTab & T.Item2 & vbTab & T.Item3)
    Next
```