# Handling big Data imported from csv

Tags: .net, arrays, csv, dataset, bigdata

I have R connected to my vb.net project. R give me a .csv file with about 10000 rows and 500 columns. I want to use these data to create PowerPoint Slides with diagrams and so on. I could put these data into an array or into a dataset, using streamreader? But before i start i would like to know what the best way is to store the data? Conserning performance and usablility.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050112/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-a-net-datatable
I think it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One absolutely user-friendly lib - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader