# Creating a report from class - Is it possible ? Report viewer

Tags: c#, reporting-services, text-files, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I have a simple customers Managment winform applicaton .
The app is build on text files and not on database .
Each customer has a folder which inside there is a txt file that contains the information.
(ex: ID , NAME , DATE , EMAIL)
I created a class that reads the information and returns a dictionary .
Key is the parameter (ex : CustomerID ) and Value is the value for the customer (ex: 100).

Now I would like to set a report using report viewer control. 
I want the report to show all customers and their information.
I managed in the past to do that for a data that is in a database , 
but is it possible to get my desired report when the information located in a txt files ?
If so , where do I begin / Can anyone show my an example ?

Thank you for your help.
Shuki

Comment: You could make your app read the files and save the Info to a temp DB, then pass that to report viewer and parse out.

Comment: how can I create a temp DB ?

Comment: It sounds like you have stored the data as comma delimited (CSV). If that is the case, what about reading the data into a data table? Check the thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050112/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-a-net-datatable

Comment: You could convert the data dictionary into a System.Data.DataTable and use that to create the RDS (Report Data Source) to hand to the ReportViewer. (This all assuming you're using ReportViewer in Local-Mode as opposed to RemoteProcessing-Mode)