# Encode to UTF-8 the content of a Row.Add() methond when binding DataGrid with .txt file content

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to encode the content of the Row.Add() into UTF-8. Now its ANSI. Searching online I came across some articles.

So my DataGrid table method looks like:

```cs
public DataTable ConvertToDataTable(string filePath)
        {
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

            // Take the first 10 lines
            var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath).Take(10);

            // Split each line and create an integer sequence where each value 
            // is the number of the splitted elements
            // then get the max value present in this sequence
            var max = lines.Select(x => x.Split('\t').Length).Max();

            // First line contains headers
            string[] headers = lines.First().Split('\t');

            // Now create the table with the max number of columns present
            for (int col = 0; col < max; col++)
                tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(headers[col]));

            //Use the Rows.Add method that accepts an object array
            foreach (string line in lines.Skip(1))
            {

                //tbl.Rows.Add(line.Split('\t'));

                var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
                
                byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(tbl.Rows.Add(line.Split('\t')));

                var myReturnedString = utf8.GetString(utfBytes);

                tbl.Rows.Add(myReturnedString);
            }

            foreach (DataRow dr in tbl.Rows)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(dr["Nationality"]);

                string s = dr["Nationality"].ToString();

                byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s);
                dr["Nationality"] = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                Debug.WriteLine(dr["Nationality"]);
            }

            return tbl;
        }
```

XAML code to design the application

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestEnvironment.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestEnvironment"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:dragablz="clr-namespace:Dragablz;assembly=Dragablz"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        Height="850" Width="1440" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>

        <!--Grid 1-->
        <Grid Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF348DE2">
            <TextBlock Text="DQ Tool Loading screen" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Arial" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20 0">
                <Button Content="FAQ" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Content="CONTACT" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Content="MY ACCOUNT" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Name="MinimizeButton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="MinimizeButton_Click">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowMinimize"/>
                </Button>
                <Button Name="PowerButton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="PowerButton_Click">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ExitToApp"/>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <!--Grid 2-->
        <Grid Margin="0 60 0 0">
            <dragablz:TabablzControl SelectionChanged="TabablzControl_SelectionChanged" RenderTransformOrigin="0.948,0.607">
                <dragablz:TabablzControl.BorderBrush>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF21499A"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4DB3FA" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </dragablz:TabablzControl.BorderBrush>
                <dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
                    <dragablz:InterTabController/>
                </dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
                <TabItem Header="LOAD FILES">
                    <Grid x:Name="GridMain" Height="900" Background="LightGray">
                        <!--Grid Columns-->
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!--Grid Rows-->
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="6*" />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                 Height="40"
                                 Text="File Path imported"
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 FontFamily="Arial"  
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 Name="FileNameTextBox"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Button x:Name="BrowseButton" 
                                Content="Browse a file" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                Width="120" 
                                Click="BrowseButton_Click" 
                                RenderTransformOrigin="1.047,0.821" 
                                Height="40"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                   Height="40"
                                   Text="TextBlock" 
                                   FontFamily="Arial"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   Name="TextBlock1"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Grid.Row="2"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                        <!--
                        <DockPanel Grid.Row="2"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <DataGrid x:Name="grid" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                      CanUserResizeRows="False"
                                      IsReadOnly="True"
                                      MinHeight="100" 
                                      SelectionMode="Single" 
                                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DockPanel>
                        -->
                        <Border BorderBrush="BlacK" 
                                BorderThickness="3"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Width="1300"
                                Height="700"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <DataGrid Name="grid"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                                  IsReadOnly="True"
                                  Height="700"
                                  Width="1300"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  Grid.Row="2"
                                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            </DataGrid>
                        </Border>
                        <Button x:Name="LoadButton"
                                Focusable="False"
                                IsEnabled="False"
                                Content="Load"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                Width="120" 
                                Click="LoadButton_Click" 
                                RenderTransformOrigin="1.047,0.821" 
                                Height="40"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="FILES LAYOUT">
                    <TextBlock Text="Amazing designs!" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="BUSINESS CHECKS">
                    <TextBlock Text="Ask for any question!" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </TabItem>

            </dragablz:TabablzControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

App.xaml file (note that the custom nuget packages Dragablz, MaterialDesignThemes have been installed)

```xml
<Application x:Class="TestEnvironment.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestEnvironment"
             xmlns:dragablz="clr-namespace:Dragablz;assembly=Dragablz"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- primary color -->
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <!-- include your primary palette -->
                    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/MaterialDesignColor.blue.xaml" />
                        <!--blue instead of purple-->
                    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

                    <!--
                            include three hues from the primary palette (and the associated forecolours).
                            Do not rename, keep in sequence; light to dark.
                        -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100}"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100Foreground}"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary500}"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary500Foreground}"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary500}"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary700Foreground}"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>

                <!-- secondary colour -->
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <!-- include your secondary pallette -->
                    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/MaterialDesignColor.blue.xaml" />
                        <!--blue instead of purple-->
                    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

                    <!-- include a single secondary accent color (and the associated forecolour) -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource Accent100}"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Accent200Foreground}"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>

                <!-- Include the Dragablz Material Design style -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Dragablz;component/Themes/materialdesign.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- tell Dragablz tab control to use the Material Design theme -->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type dragablz:TabablzControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabablzControlStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Output

[image]

But inside the Row.Add() method I get an error:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataRow' to 'char[]'

Any thoughts on how to solve it?

A dummy [TXT file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XGgYf-lkLB9UXz9lOrGA2uH-9ozt8y-_/view?usp=sharing) to test replicate the wrong encoding

Output based on the answer given in comments

[image]

Code

```cs
        public DataTable ConvertToDataTable(string filePath)
        {
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

            // Take the first 10 lines
            var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath).Take(10);

            // Split each line and create an integer sequence where each value 
            // is the number of the splitted elements
            // then get the max value present in this sequence
            var max = lines.Select(x => x.Split('\t').Length).Max();

            // First line contains headers
            string[] headers = lines.First().Split('\t');

            // Now create the table with the max number of columns present
            for (int col = 0; col < max; col++)
                tbl.Columns.Add(headers[col], typeof(string));

            //Use the Rows.Add method that accepts an object array
            /*foreach (string line in lines.Skip(1))
            {

                tbl.Rows.Add(line.Split('\t'));

            }*/

            //UTF-8 encoding

            var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

            foreach (string line in lines.Skip(1))
            {
                IEnumerable<string> utf8Values = line.Split('\t')
                    .Select(s => utf8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, utf8,
                        Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s))));
                tbl.Rows.Add(utf8Values);
            }

            foreach (DataRow dr in tbl.Rows)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(dr["Nationality"]);

                string s = dr["Nationality"].ToString();

                byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s);
                dr["Nationality"] = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                Debug.WriteLine(dr["Nationality"]);
            }

            return tbl;
        }
```

Comment: From : tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(headers[col])); To : tbl.Columns.Add(headers[col],typeof(string));

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for the resposne. The problem is not in the DataColumn method but  in the Row.Add() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Split` method returns a `string[]`. You can use the `Encoding.Convert` method to convert between different encodings:

```
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
foreach (string line in lines.Skip(1))
{
    IEnumerable<string> utf8Values = line.Split('\t')
        .Select(s => utf8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, utf8, 
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s))));
    tbl.Rows.Add(utf8Values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response mm8. But the output is not what expected. Even though the code is correct. Please check my updated SO for a screenshot of your answer

Comment: What's the value of `lines` and `utf8Values` when you debug then? You haven't provided any sample data...

Comment: Please check for my update. Apologize for non-providing any sample. Would you like to also upload the xaml file with the DataGrid created?

Comment: Hello mm8 can you please check my updated code in order to create the application and replicate the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Issue resolved based on your code snippet mm8. Thanks a lot for your help