# Convert IEnumerable string array to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linqtocsv

I have a csv file delimited with pipe(|). I am reading it using the following line of code:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> lineFields = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).Select(line => line.Split('|'));
```

Now, I need to bind this to a `GridView`. So I am creating a dynamic `DataTable` as follows:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
int i = 0;
foreach (string[] order in lineFields)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {                        
        foreach (string column in order)
        {
            DataColumn _Column = new DataColumn();
            _Column.ColumnName = column;
            dt.Columns.Add(_Column);
            i++;
            //Response.Write(column);
            //Response.Write("\t");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int j = 0;
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        foreach (string value in order)
        {
            row[j] = value;                            
            j++;

            //Response.Write(column);
            //Response.Write("\t");
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    //Response.Write("\n");
}
```

This works fine. But I want to know if there is a better way to convert `IEnumerable<string[]>` to a `DataTable`. I need to read many CSVs like this, so I think the above code might have performance issues.

Comment: if its delimited with `|` then its not CSV. They would be Comma Seperated Values.

Comment: @Jodrell It can also refer to Character Separated Values

Comment: There some auto-generating software that creates these files.

Comment: @DarrenYoung, do you have some reference to back that up, its new to me and not immediately obvious via a quick search?

Comment: Can you assume every row has the same number of columns as the first?

Comment: @Jodrell:Please refer this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/)

Comment: @Jodrell One from IBM http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSY4B9_4.1.0/com.ibm.mu.doc_4.1/fsyug162.html

Comment: @Jodrell: Yes, It has exact same number of columns in all rows.

Comment: looks like a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050112/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-a-net-datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since, in your linked example, the file has a header row.

```
const char Delimiter = '|';

var dt = new DataTable;
using (var m = File.ReadLines(filePath).GetEnumerator())
{
    m.MoveNext();
    foreach (var name in m.Current.Split(Delimiter))
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(name);
    }

    while (m.MoveNext())
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(m.Current.Split(Delimiter));
    }
}
```

This reads the file **in one pass**.

Comment: @jodrell my code `loading it all into memory`? to my knowledge he does not even once. see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,933

Comment: @lomed, yours loads it only into the `DataTable`, thanks to `ReadLines`/`ReadLine`, the OPs, as you noticed, uses `ReadAllLines`. If benchmarked, `ReadAllLines` might be marginally faster for smaller files. However, for large files efficient use of memory is likely to be a greater concern.

Comment: @jordell you right. but if you use ReadAllLines, you can use normal `For`. Still, you need to edit your words, that there was a proposal made by loading the file twice.

Answer (score 2):

### Starting from .Net 4:

use `ReadLines`.

```
DataTable FileToDataTable(string FilePath)
{

    var dt = new DataTable();

    IEnumerable<string[]> lineFields = File.ReadLines(FilePath).Select(line => line.Split('|'));
    dt.Columns.AddRange(lineFields.First().Select(i => new DataColumn(i)).ToArray());

    foreach (var order in lineFields.Skip(1))
        dt.Rows.Add(order);

    return dt;
}
```

(**edit:** instead this code, use the code of @Jodrell answer, This prevents double charging of the Enumerator).

### Before .Net 4:

use streaming:

```
DataTable FileToDataTable1(string FilePath)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    using (var st = new StreamReader(FilePath))
    {
        // first line procces
        if (st.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            var order = st.ReadLine().Split('|');
            dt.Columns.AddRange(order.Select(i => new DataColumn(i)).ToArray());
        }

        while (st.Peek() >= 0)
            dt.Rows.Add(st.ReadLine().Split('|'));
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: if you assume that each row has the same number of columns, you should delete the condition in the loop and instead add code before the start of the loop reads the first line and checks the number of columns of the first row only.

Comment: If I remove the condition, it works fine. But the header column is also created as a row at the top.

Comment: first rows of the file has column headers.

Comment: This doesn't add the column headers.

Comment: if you use `ReadLines` the @Jodrell code its slightly more efficient (It creates only one instance of the Enumerator).