# Best way to convert Stream - CSV to Data Table

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

We are receiving a CSV file as Stream. Now we are creating the data table from the stream as below

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] rows = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = rows[i].Replace("\"", "");
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

It's taking some time to create the Data Table as CSV in Stream contains lot of records. We want to have the best solution to do the same. Can you please share,  If you know any other better solution than this.

Comment: refer this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050112/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-a-net-datatable?lq=1

Comment: In above post a answer suggested to use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider with your CSV file. Here is the answer; http://stackoverflow.com/a/1050278/2130976

Answer (score 0):

Catching exception can slow down your process. Try to handle all cases in the code.

```
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
            continue;
  }
```