# Loading a CSV File to DataTable - Error reading CSV File With JET.OLEDB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm filling a table in MySQL from a CSV file using an application developed with C# and ASP.NET MVC4. I have an issue loading CSV files.

I'm reading the CSV file, filling a DataTable, doing validations about regular expressions and inserting finally in MySql database. Great.

The problem is with the data formats in the CSV file. Looks like when I read the Csv file, c # does not Distinguish between strings and double.

When I load just numbers (doubles) with separator, "." or "," the method does not recognize the contents of cvs file.

I've reviewed formatting in regional settings and language and don't get a solution.

Let me explain please,

## VIEW

From the view **Load** I've some like.

```
 //Here I can choose a Csv File and print the content
 @model Pharmtech.Models.myModule.FilesModel
 <div>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "myModule", FormMethod.Post,
 new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
  <h3>Choose a Csv File</h3>
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Cargar">
 }
 <p>@TempData["Messages"]</p>
```

## CONTROLLER

When the submit active the **ActionResult** UploadFile

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        FilesModel model = new FilesModel();
        DataTable dt;

       //Check if file is not null
        if (file != null)
        {
            //Built the path
            string path = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "-") 
                          + (file.FileName).ToLower();

            //Check File Extension
            if (model.FileCsv(path))
            {                    
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + path));
                dt = model.getDataTableFromCsvFile(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), path);

                //Check if dt it's not empty
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    //Save in TempData["Messages"] the dt content
                    if (model.printDataTableFromCsv(dt))
                    {
                        TempData["Messages"] = model.AllData;
                    }
                }
                else TempData["Messages"] = "Csv File is Empty";
            }else TempData["Messages"] = "File it's not Csv File";
        }else TempData["Messages"] = "Please upload a Csv File";

       return RedirectToAction("Load");
    }
```

## MODEL

I've written some methods in **FilesModel** Model

**Validating Csv File Extension**

```
    public bool FileCsv(string fileName)
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        switch (ext.ToLower())
        {
            case ".csv": return true;
            default: return false;
        }
    }
```

**Get a DataTable from CSV File**

```
//Get DataTable from Csv File    
    public  DataTable getDataTableFromCsvFile(String path, String file)
    {
        //Quit double spaces
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + file, Regex.Replace
               (System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + file), "  ", " "));

        //Defining connection
        string connectionStringCsv = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                path + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited'";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionStringCsv);
            objConn.Open();

            OleDbCommand objCmdSelect 
              = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + file + "]", objConn);
             OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

            objAdapter.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
            objAdapter.Fill(dt);
            objConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Do something
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

**Finally print the DataTable Content**

```
 public string AllData;
 public bool printDataTableFromCsv(DataTable masterCsv)
 {
     AllData = "";
     int row = 0;
     //Check if DataTable it's not emtpy
     if (masterCsv.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
         //Going through DataTable and print rows
         foreach (DataRow rows in masterCsv.Rows)
         {
           AllData += "Row: " + row 
             + "=" + rows["DATA"].ToString() + ". ";
           row++;
                }
         }            
          if (row != 0) { return true; }
          else { return false; }
}
```

## INPUT and OUTPUTS

Some examples:

### Output 1

Input 1, when the files content

```
 //DATA
 //30.33
 //20.45

 //Output is 1         
 //I get: "Row: 0=3033. Row: 1=2045" 
  //**Is to say, remove the "."
```

### Output 2

Input 2, when the files content

```
 //DATA
 //20.33
 //Hello World

 //Output is
 //Row: 0=2033.Row: 1=.
 //**Is to say, remove the letters
```

### Output 3

Input 3, when the files content

```
 //DATA
 //20.33
 //Hello World
 //This is, a problem

 //Output is        
 //Row: 0=20.33.Row: 1=Hello World.Row: 2=This is, a problem.
```

## Hypothesis

I guess the error is in the reading of csv, C # tries to assign to the column of the DataTable a type of data

Sometimes, I choose a csv file with just double the print is "File Empty"
I tried with .csv and .csv MS-DOS

Somebody have any idea that what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you tell us which row is the place of the exception?

Comment: this question has too much going on. Can you isolate a single row that is causing the problem and if that problem is in the reading of the csv, processing it into a datatable, or saving it to MySql?

Comment: I get the error just printing the DataTable. I quit all validations and operations about database.

Comment: so you get the error on 
AllData[row] = "Row: " + row + " -> Field DATA "
                         + "= " + rows["DATA"].ToString();
?
What's the error message?

Comment: {System.InvalidCastException: Can not convert an object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.String []'. The program breaks when is showing the content of TempData["Messages"]

Comment: Is rows["DATA"] a String array?

Comment: AllData is a string array rows is the varible that go through the for each, "DATA" is the column name on CSV File

Comment: What is the type of rows["DATA"]? Is AllData[row] = "Row: " + row + " -> Field DATA "
                         + "= " + rows["DATA"].ToString(); the row you have the problem at?

Comment: Yes, it is. The problem in the original project is that remove "." from a column . I do this test and find that when the column has "." or "," the program break.  AllData is a string array, rows is an int. rows["DATA"] is sometimes int or somethings string, or mixed

Answer (score 1):

> I guess the error is in the reading of csv, C # tries to assign to the column of the DataTable a type of data

If your columns have mixed data types, or contain data which may be read as different data types(ie "4-4-97" which can be both a date or a string) you should use the `imex` switch in your connection string.

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + someVariablePath + ";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;IMEX=1;\"";
```

Or use a schema file and gain more control over how your data is read. Note that if you switch to the newer Data Access Components (`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`), The `IMEX` switch has no effect and you must use a schema file if you wish to control data type.

[Schema file Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver)

```
[myfile.txt]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
MaxScanRows=5
```

It's not that C# tries to define the type, its the data driver that makes that decision and tells your code what is coming. The driver reads the first `n` lines and defines a type. Then passed `n` lines it passes a value that no longer matches the type.

```
col1
1
2
3
4
5
a
7
true
9
```

The column above could create a problem. Based on the first 5 records, we're dealing with `int`. So when the column definitions are made the column is deemed to be an `int`. From then on, your code is expecting to see numbers in that column. But then on record 6, there's a string. And record 8, could be a `string` or a `bool`. The data driver doesn't care but, your code does when you feed it something like `"a"` when it's expecting a number.

Comment: Thanks friend, it's a clear explication of what's going on. I tested IMEX=1 in connection string and don't work. I'm not sure on create the schema, because this method must work to twenty seven (27) diferents Csv Files (diferents names files, diferents headers, I need built the file name by today date), but I'll try it. Thanks so very much.

Answer (score 0):

A **partial solution** is quote the CSV values inside double quotation marks (This way, JET will treat all the read values like string) and then parse them from C #.

After several attempts of solution and the evaluation of the time of consumption in the load, I decided not to use Jet.OLEDB

I think there are more appropriate ways of doing this, using LINQ for example.

I also found these two projects:

[A fast CSV Reader](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)  by **Sebastian Lorien**

[A portable and Efficient parse for float files](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F)

[Delimited Text Extension File](https://github.com/Core-Techs/Common/blob/master/CoreTechs.Common/Text/DelimitedTextExtensions.cs#L22http://)

**Let me share this answer**, helped me find a solution:

[How to read a CSV file into a .NET Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050112/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-a-net-datatable)

Thanks very much