# Read a CSV file into a **typed** DataTable

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have a **typed** DataTable generated by Visual Studio from a database schema and I would like to populate it from a CSV file.

I have seen [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050112/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-a-net-datatable) for a plain DataTable but it wouldn't work for a typed DataTable.

Obviously I could read a DataTable first and then copy it row-by-row, field-by-field into my typed DataTable but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: 1) You've tagged your question [tag:csvhelper] but none of the answers to your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050112/3744182) actually use this [library](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).  Which answer(s) from that question have you tried and do not work?  2) What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall any library does it for you out of the box. If you are looking an answer how to convert DataTable to Typed Datatable, here is one approach

```
DataTable data = GetDataFromCSV();
MyTypedDataTable myData = new MyTypedDataTable();
myData.Merge(data);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That certainly qualifies for "elegant", although it may not be very resource-effective. Thanks.