# How to read CSV files using OdbcConnection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, odbc

I have a docker container with .NET core as the base image. I have few CSV files mounted under `app` and I am trying to read them by establishing an `OdbcConnection`.

I have the following installed

```
unixODBC msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

This is what I have currently

```
fileSource = "/app/DataStore/FolderForCsvs";
string conSt = string.Format("Driver={{Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}};Dbq={0};Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt", fileSource);
var connectionString = new OdbcConnection(conSt);
string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM `{0}`", tableName);
using (var odbcConnection = connectionString)
{
  odbcConnection.Open(); // errror
  using (var odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(query, odbcConnection))
  {
      var dataReader = odbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
      while (dataReader.Read())
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Inside");
      }
   }
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
 ---> System.Exception: Exception in row row insert
 ---> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)' : file not found
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection, OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
```

Below are my odbc settings:

```
[root@d5dc11d8c347 app]# odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

[root@d5dc11d8c347 app]# cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0
Threading=1
UsageCount=1

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.1.so.0.1
UsageCount=1
```

I am not really sure how the odbc settings should be. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why, when you can just read them as files without needing a database driver, using any one of the tens of popular csv reading libraries or even file.readlines and string split if you're desperate/they're simple

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you. Yeah, that's the first path I took, and unfortunately, I was having issues using CsvHelper when loading the data into DataTable for nullable GUIDs. I thought I would try this way so that I get everything as strings that could be bulk inserted.

Comment: Did you ask a question about the nullable guid issue? What about just reading those guids as strings? Or writing your own value converter (very easy to do )

Comment: Yeah, I did (https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/discussions/1874). Do you mind elaborating on the value converter?  I want to try that out.

Comment: I answered your previous question

Answer (score 0):

To add to @CaiusJard: ODBC for CSV in Docker containers is taking the log way around.

Simply use(I am lazy) FileHelpers from nuget to read you csv into an object list or even a datatable.  I have also added a link to use Filehelpers if the csv layout file is unknown. Datatable example is in second link also.

[Filehelpers Example reading delimited file](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadFileDelimited/)

[Read unknown csv format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361716/using-filehelpers-to-read-a-dynamic-csv-to-datatable)