# How can I remove a CSV's header when importing it to a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, csv, gridview

I would like to ask if you have a source code for importing csv files to gridview in an ASP.NET web form.

What I want to do is remove the header on the file and display it in the grid view.

Here is a SC of my file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read the CSV into a DataTable and then bind it into the GridView:

```
public void bindGrid()
{
var dt=GetDataTableFromCsv("path_to_csv_file",true);
GridView1.DataSource=dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

From [How to read a CSV file into a .NET Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050112/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-a-net-datatable/1050278#1050278):

> ```
> DataTable GetDataTableFromCsv(string path, bool isFirstRowHeader)
> {
>     string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";
>
>     string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
>     string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
>
>     string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";
>
>     using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
>               @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + 
>               ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
>     using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
>     using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
>     {
>         DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
>         dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
>         adapter.Fill(dataTable);
>         return dataTable;
>     }
> }
> ```