# Data Type Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, csv, sqldatatypes

I am facing an issue while importing the data from a csv file and storing it in SQL Server using the C# `StreamReader`. All the columns in the csv files are read as `varchar` datatype while inserting into the database table. How do I insert in a proper way so that columns with numerical values get stored as `int`/`float`,  strings as `varchar`, etc.

Can anyone suggest a proper way to do this task?

Can anyone help with a robust and generic code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it, the table is autogenerated ? if not why don't you put the good types manually ?

Comment: You need to convert your data types. If you share a portion of your code, I can show you how to modify it to make that happen.

Comment: Use CsvHelper to read the file, where you would have a class that represents the data with the correct data types. That's a very solid package.

Comment: How are you inserting? SqlCommand or SqlBulkCopy? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I maintain a library that can handle this quite easily: Sylvan.Data.Csv. The key is that you need to provide a schema for the incoming data so that the SqlClient library knows how to deal with it.

```
// the "Schema" type comes from Sylvan.Data package
var schema =
    new Schema
    .Builder()
    .Add<int>("Id")
    .Add<string>("Name")
    .Add<DateTime?>("ModifiedDate")
    .Build();


var opts = new CsvDataReaderOptions
{
    Schema = new CsvSchema(schema)
};

// Create, or CreateAsync can be passed the name of a file or a TextReader.
using var csv = CsvDataReader.Create(csvFilefame, opts);

SqlConnection conn = ...;

var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = 0; // no timeout.
bcp.DestinationTableName = "MyTable";
bcp.BatchSize = 50000;
bcp.WriteToServer(csv);
```

The Schema type is defined in the Sylvan.Data package, which is currently pre-release only, so if you don't feel comfortable taking a dependency on that (understandable), you can implement your own `ICsvSchemaProvider` which is pretty easy. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61256368/190371) has an example of implementing your own typed schema provider.

If you have any questions, or issues feel free to open an issue over at https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is to do the load into a temporary table and have all the columns as character-based with max-length allowed / expected.  Then, after all the input columns, I would add the columns as their final data format so they wont have any impact on import stream / comma/tab delimited format.

Once the data is imported into the temp table, then run an update query to get to the final format of int, decimal, float, bit, date/time, etc.

Finally, if all goes well, then you can do all your queries or insert into from the select from the temp file as needed for final import.

Ex:

temp table has

```
FirstName  varchar(20),
LastName   varchar(20),
BirthDateText varchar(10),
SalaryText varchar(10),
AnyOtherColumns varchar(10),
RealBirthDate Timestamp
Salary  decimal
```

So, the import fills up from `FirstName` to the `AnyOtherColumns`, but now you can run update commands to properly convert into the respective `REALBirthDate` and `Salary` columns of data.

No third-party, completely under your control and data cleansing can be done / validated before it goes into its final destination too.