# Read ODBC semicolon-delimited .csv

Tags: powershell, csv, odbc, connection-string

Currently I am trying to read a semicolon-delimited `.csv` file into a DataTable using ODBC from PowerShell.

The DataTable does not have the correct columns and seems to ignore the delimiter.

My Schema.ini

```
[data.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=Delimited(;)
```

The code:

```
$SourceFolder = [String]::Format("{0}\Data\Source\", $PWD)
$fileName = "data.csv"
$driver = "{Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}"
$tableName = $fileName -replace ".csv",""
$readFileQuery = [String]::Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", $fileName)

$connectionString = [String]::Format("Driver={0};Dbq={1};Extensions=csv,txt;Extended Properties='FMT=Delimited(;);HDR=Yes'", $driver, $SourceFolder)
$odbcConnection = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection($connectionString)
$odbcConnection.Open()

$odbcCommand = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($readFileQuery, $odbcConnection)
$odbcDataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter        
$dataSet.Tables.Add($tableName)
$odbcDataAdapter.SelectCommand = $odbcCommand
$odbcDataAdapter.Fill($dataSet.Tables[$tableName]) | Out-Null
$dataSet.Tables[$tableName]
```

I changed the connectionstring to add and remove various extended properties, among format, fmt (with or without character). Hardcoding the delimiter in the registry, setting it to various values in the Schema.ini.

Due to the size of the .csv files, it is not reasonable to replace the semi-colons with commas.

P.s. this is a follow-up to [Read .csv from PowerShell using ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Do you have a sample CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it need to be in PowerShell?  [How to read a CSV file into a .NET Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050112/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-a-net-datatable)

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F

If it has to be in PowerShell here are somethings to check:

- `Schema.ini` has to be located in the same directory as the .csv file you're trying to read.
- `{Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}` may be having issues, make sure it installed and configured correctly.
- You hardcoded the delimiter in the registry. Check to make sure it wasn't overwritten.

[https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/csv-odbc-powershell.rst#:~:text=To%20retrieve%20CSV%20data%20in%20PowerShell%2C%20call%20the,initialize%20the%20OdbcCommand%20object%20and%20then%20call%20ExecuteNonQuery](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/csv-odbc-powershell.rst#:%7E:text=To%20retrieve%20CSV%20data%20in%20PowerShell%2C%20call%20the,initialize%20the%20OdbcCommand%20object%20and%20then%20call%20ExecuteNonQuery).

Comment: Creating `Schema.ini` in the same directory as the `.csv` files solved it!